# ENOMEM from popen() for system(), while there is enough memory

Tags: c, linux, memory, fork

I have two relatively big applications(processes) running in embedded Linux on ARM with 3 RAM banks (in Linux cmdline: mem=128M mem=256M@0x90000000 mem=128M@0xA0000000).
One application processes user commands, between which there may be request to run ordinary Linux shell command. This is implemented as:

`if((fp=popen(UserCommand, "r")) == NULL) return(errno));
fgets(ReplyString, 128, fp);
Res = pclose(fp);`

The first line returns errno=12 - ENOMEM even for the simplest command like "pwd", although there is plenty of memory:

`root@dm814x-evm:~# free
              total         used         free       shared      buffers 
  Mem:       461472        38576       422896            0          152
 Swap:            0            0            0
Total:       461472        38576       422896`

As far as I understand there is more than 400MB of free space!
For the first test purpose I also cancelled the second process - ops!, the error has gone!!!
For the second test I run telnet and executed the command via it (while both processes were running) - no problem, works fine.

So, where is the catch?

Comment: I don't remember if `popen()` can call `malloc` down inside its implementation.  If so, the problem may be that you have previously corrupted the heap with improper `malloc` or `free` usage elsewhere in your code, and the corruption doesn't get detected until `popen` stumbles over it.

Comment: Is overcommit enabled on your system? (`cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`)

Comment: If it's disabled, you need the amount of your app's memory usage to make a `fork` (which is what `popen` does). If you don't want to have overcommit enabled, you could get away with much less memory if you create your pipe manually (with `pipe()`) and use `posix_spawn` to create the process with the pipe connected to it.

Comment: It would be worth pinging glibc with a bug report to that effect: popen should be implemented with posix_spawn, not fork. musl already does it that way.

Comment: @PSkocik, yes, I do have the following:  
sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=2;
sysctl -w vm.overcommit_ratio=90;
sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=40;
sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=3;
Please, can you explain more detailed the influence of the overcommit in this case? Please!

Comment: @leonp I'd try enabling it fully (`echo 1>/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`). The reason it might fail without it is that `fork()` will actually have to reserve every page that the parent process has reserved. That's a waste if you're going to `execve` soon.

Comment: @PSkocik, The reason I use the above mentioned settings is that my application has extensive writing to the disk. And I don't want to collect much data in ram, as when the power is lost I need to push everything to the disk.
But, please, explain more detailed what happens now - I don't understand your brief explanation. Sorry, excuses for my lack of knowledge/understanding...

Comment: @leonp Please try `sudo sh -c 'echo 1>/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory'` or compiling with [musl-gcc](https://www.musl-libc.org/download.html) instead of just `gcc`. If any of the two strategies solved your problem, I may try and explain why.

Comment: @PSkocik Yes, it worked! No more errors. Now, according to my measures some 3-4 years ago, the performance of writing to disk goes down if I close overcommit at all. 1. What happens? Why this helped? 2. What should I do with the disk performance, if I cancel overcommit? 3. Why this error exists when I run from NAND, but does not (works fine) when running from NFS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If popen is implemented with `fork()` (as it currently is in glibc) rather than `posix_spawn()` or `vfork()`, then you need as much memory as what the parent is using for the operation to succeed. This allocation might fail if overcommit on your system is disabled, so to solve your problem, you should do one of the following:

1. fully enable overcommit on your system

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo 1>/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory'
   ```
2. use a libc library that doesn't implement `popen()` with `fork()` ([musl](https://www.musl-libc.org) is an [example](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/popen.c))
3. do what `popen` does yourself but express it in terms of `pipe()` and `posix_spawn()`, rather than the classical `pipe()`, `dup2()`,`fork()`,`execve()` combo.

(`popen` 1) creates a pipe 2) wraps one end of the pipe in a `FILE` and 3) creates a process and wires up the other end of the pipe to the processe's `stdin` or `stdout`, saving the process's `pid` in the `FILE` structure)

The problem with the classical `fork()` + `execve()` way of process creation is that if overcommit is disabled, `fork()` has to be pessimistic and assume the child might continue running the parent process, which would mean the child needs every page of the parent's memory. With overcommit enabled, the memory is borrowed and problems (the out-of-memory killer) only arise if the borrowed memory is accessed (which it won't be if the process will call `execve()` soon). With overcommit disabled, all of the memory has to be reserved, which is why it's likely to fail if the `fork` call is made from a larger process.

Comment: Please, I am lost. According to the, for example, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-memory-captun.html, setting overcommit_memory to 1 or 2 is almost the same in my case, as I have no swap memory and overcommit_ratio=90 and 'free' shows 400MB free. Where I am wrong?

Comment: I'd use `musl` or write my own `FILE *my_popen(char const *File, char const *Mode, pid_t *Pid);` It should be a bit more efficient too.

Comment: Yes, I understand the work around you suggested and try to implement it. But still I don't understand why it doesn't work with my setting overcommit_memory=2, overcommit_ratio=90? Manual says that my settings mean that Linux has 90% of memory to assign (reserving only 10%). If 'free' report 400MB, what is the cause of the error? My process itself occupies about 30MB...

Comment: @leonp `free` only appears to be concerned with resident set sizes, which makes it useless for this. What matters is the virtual memory usage of your system. (If you `malloc` 1GiB but only touch the first page, your resident memory will go up by 4KiB (pagesize) but your virtual memory usage will go up by at least 1GiB. The 1GiB is what matter for `fork()` if overcommit is disabled).

Comment: Please, can you explain also why running from NFS works and from NAND not?
And please, also insert space in your answer between "1 >/proc..."

Comment: *rather than `posix_spawn()`* -- On Linux `posix_spawn()` is implemented with `fork()` unless called with `POSIX_SPAWN_USEVFORK`. Solaris's `posix_spawn()` implementation uses `vfork()` though.